# enclose table name containing spaces - d2rq language

Tags: sql-server, ontology, d2rq

How do I enclose table name (sql server) containing space while mapping files using `d2rq` language? table name is Compression Stats

So in my mapping file I have among other things:

```
d2rq:condition "Compression Stats.VelocityID = '2145C'" ;
```

I tried [], ```, () around table, and table.column, but nothing is working.
Does anyone know?

Comment: I don't know anything about d2rq, but maybe you could create a view onto [Compression Stats] that doesn't contain a space in the name.

Comment: Try double quotes (`"`), they are name delimiters in standard SQL (Transact-SQL supports them too), perhaps they'll be recognised by this `d2rq` thing. I guess you'll need to escape them somehow, as they are also string delimiters in this language you are using.

Comment: Have you tried double-quotes.  I have seem Crystal Reports do double-quotes for SQL Server names.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `d2rq` `mapping`. and until they fix it, I will just have to remove space in my table name